# why people use org.proj.subproj in most of java libs

Tags: jar, project-management

I wanted to go through java project publishing cycle and I've noticed people mostly use "org"."projectname".etc so i was wondering about this style advantages and why org is very much common ?

A Book or tutorial of such stuff would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org. is commonly (though not always) used for open source projects because they are released in a not-for-profit way. However, within companies you will find a lot of code using com.companyname, or even just companyname. or projectname. (the latter two styles are not recommended.) So I don't think it's true that "most people" use org - that's just what it looks like because you can't see all of that private company code on the Internet!

The reason for all this is that Sun, the company that created Java, recommends that people put classes in packages named after their domain name, reversed, and create subpackages within that to be unique within their organisation. The purpose is to avoid name clashes. That is why apache packages start with org.apache, for example - because apache's main domain name is apache.org.

Answer (score 2):

It is amazing what a simple search like "[java package naming conventions](http://www.google.co.cr/search?hl=en&client=safari&q=java%20package%20naming%20conventions&aq=f&aqi=g1g-j1&aql=&oq=)" can yield in [Google](http://www.google.com).

- [Java Package Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions)
  by Wikipedia.
- [The Java Tutorial: Naming a
  Package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)
- [Java Language Specification: Unique
  Package Names](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/packages.doc.html#40169)

Comment: you're so right, I always start by google, but pardon my humble knowledge I couldn't find the right words to search, thanks